# How to use twitch-passport for authentication? Node Express Passport Next

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, next.js

I am working on setting up authentication for my website. I would like to have a few signup/connect account option in the future, but am focusing solely on twitch authentication for now.
I am using `Next.js` for server-side rendering.
I have copied the code from http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-twitch/ and store my client_id and secret in the .env file.

**server.js->**

```
const port     = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev      = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const nextApp  = next({dev});
const express        = require("express");
const bodyParser     = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser   = require("cookie-parser");
const cookieSession  = require("cookie-session");
const passport       = require("passport");
const twitchStrategy = require("passport-twitch").Strategy;

const app = express();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(cookieSession({secret:"somesecrettokenhere"}));

  app.use(passport.initialize());

  passport.use(new twitchStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitch/callback",
      scope: "user_read"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      console.log("profile: "+profile);
    }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
  });

  app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/Index', req.query);
  });

  app.get("/auth/twitch", passport.authenticate("twitch", {forceVerify: true}));

  app.get("/auth/twitch/callback",
  passport.authenticate("twitch", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function(req, res) {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect("/");
  });

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/Index', req.query);
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    //console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```

It does take me to twitch authentication when I hit the `/auth/twitch` route, then gives **"failed to fetch user profile"** after. I am completely new to authentication and would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

edit: as a side-note, I plan to use uid-safe for the cookie secret.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the sense to stick a console log in the passport-twitch file to see the error from twitch saying that v3 is dead, v5 is alive. Then saw that it was calling kraken. Updated to passport-twitch-helix and voila.